# Count of Orders per User ID within a time frame

Tags: powerbi

I have a table (Orders) that contains information about orders: User_id, Order_date and Order_price.

This table is linked to a date.table. What I would like to have is a measure that counts how many users made 1,2,3,4,5,.... orders. Basically a histogram of count of orders per user.  I need to be able to filter this measure later on based on specific dates.

Maybe I don't have to realize this in a measure but in a seperate table or column? Not really sure how to proceed here. Any help is appreciated. I have created this measure using SUMMARIZE in a seperate table, but this is of course no longer sensitive to filtering by order date.

Best

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to figure out how many instances of orders there were for each `User ID` you can use the formula below. As you filter you date with a slicer this will adjust accordingly. Make sure to pull User Id somewhere in your visual to show the orders by User Id.

`Orders = Countrows( [Orders] )`

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your feedback. I do not need to the number for each individual User ID. What I am after is a distribution over the entire population of users. So how many users have placed 1,2 or 3 orders over a certain period of time.

Comment: @Lukas using this count you can drag in the USER ID and it will provide a count of orders by USER ID.